# Magento 2 - Empty arguments in adapter __construct()

Tags: magento2, di, factory

I am creating an adapter for a third party module by following the Magento_Braintree structure.

In the Braintree module, they have a factory `BraintreeAdapterFactory` that creates an adapter `BraintreeAdapter` and passes some arguments. I have duplicated the same structure for my module. However, I am getting empty arguments in the `__construct()` even if I try hard coding values in my factory.

I added a `di.xml` in an attempt to fix it, but still nothing unless I hardcode values for my arguments. I have also made sure to compile, clean cache and delete files from `/generated`.

Am I missing something?

Factory:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter;

use Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

/**
 * This factory is preferable to use for Module adapter instance creation.
 */
class ModuleAdapterFactory
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var Vendor\Module\Model\Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, 
        Config $config
    ){
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Creates instance of Contentul Adapter.
     *
     * @return ContentulAdapter
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->create(
            ModuleAdapter::class,
            [
                'accessToken' => $this->config->getAccessToken(),
                'spaceId' => $this->config->getSpaceId()
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter;

use ThirdParty\Delivery\Client;

/**
* Class ModuleAdapter
* Use \Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapterFactory to create new instance of adapter.
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class ModuleAdapter
{

    /**
    * @var Client
    */
    private $client;

    /**
    * @param string $accessToken
    * @param string $spaceId
    */
    public function __construct($accessToken, $spaceId)
    {
        $this->client = new Client($accessToken, $spaceId);
    }

}
```

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapter">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="accessToken" xsi:type="string"></argument>
            <argument name="spaceId" xsi:type="string"></argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up ditching the `Magento_Braintree` method of creating a custom factory and instead referenced the classes in `Magento\Framework\Image\`. I didn't actually need any special functionality in my Factory so creating a custom one really wasn't necessary. I moved all the config code to my adapter and got/set the variables in the `__construct` method.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter;

use Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapterInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
use Module\Delivery\Client;
use Module\Delivery\Query;
use Module\Link;

/**
 * Class \Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapter
 */
class ModuleAdapter implements ModuleAdapterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $accessToken;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $spaceId;

    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @param Vendor\Module\Model\Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $config
    ){
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->accessToken = $this->config->getAccessToken();
        $this->spaceId = $this->config->getSpaceId();
        $this->client = $this->createClient($this->accessToken, $this->spaceId);
    }
```

Then I just used my adapter directly in my model class.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ContentTypes;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ContentTypes\ContentTypesInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapter;

/**
 * Class \Vendor\Module\Model\ContentTypes\Block
 */
class Block implements ContentTypesInterface
{   

    /**
     * @var ModuleAdapter
     */
    private $module;

    /**
     * @param Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapter $module
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleAdapter $module,
    ){
        $this->module = $module;
    }

    /**
     * Get All Block Entries
     *
     * @return ResourceArray
     */
    public function getAll(){
        return $this->module->getEntries();
    }
```

And to use my model in my block class, I use Magento 2's magical auto-generated factory.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\ContentTypes;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ContentTypes\BlockFactory as ContentFulFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Block extends Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Adapter\ModuleAdapterFactory
     */
    private $moduleAdapterFactory;

    /**
     * @var ResourceArray
     */
    private $entry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Config $config
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ContentFulFactory $moduleFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->moduleFactory = $moduleFactory->create();
    }
```